# Top N + Nested Sorting in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two dimensions(namely state and city) and a measure glid(i need to find the count of glid, since glid is a unique reference no.)

I want to arrange my data such that for each state i get only the top 3 or n cities having the highest count of glids , and i want the rest of the cities to be clubbed under a separate category, say "others".

I have done my due research but since i am new to tableau , could not fathom it.

Please be more elaborate in answering. I am attaching an image for further help
[image]

P.S. It can be done by grouping but since there are too many states and cities , it would be very tedious

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to

- Sort 'State' and 'City' in descending order on Field:'Gild' and Aggregation: Count
- Create calculated field `ranking` having definition as `index()`
- Drag it to 'Rows'. Right click this field in here and select 'Edit table calculation'. Select 'Compute Using': Specific Dimensions, Below that check 'State' & 'City' (in order), 'At the level':Deepest, 'Restarting Every': State and other default selections.
- Create parameter `Top 3` - Data type: Integer; Current value: 3; Display format: Automatic; Allowable values: Range; Minimum:3; Maximum:10; Step size:1
- Right click this parameter and select 'Show parameter control'
- Create calculated field `Top_3_calc`

---

```
IF  [ranking] <= [Top 3] THEN "Top Values"
ELSE "Others"
END
```

---

- Drag this calculated field to 'Rows'. Right click this field in here and select 'Edit table calculation'. Select 'Compute Using': Specific Dimensions, Below that check 'State' & 'City' (in order), 'At the level':Deepest, 'Restarting Every': State and other default selections.

After this you would require to do few cosmetic changes in order to achieve your specific requirement.

*Pls don't forget to let us know if it helped :)*

Comment: Hi Prem Appreciate your help, however it does not seem to give me the required solution.It gives the following result

Comment: Hi Prem Appreciate your help, however it does not seem to give me the required solution.I want all the cities of each state (barring the top3) to be merged under a single category by the name of 'others' and display the count of glids against each city.Against each state, only the top 3 cities and 'others' category must be displayed along with with the count

Comment: @Rahul - I would suggests you to kindly update your original question with the desired output sample so that we can guide you in right direction.

Comment: The solution that you provided inserted two new columns in front of state and city- namely ranking(showing the rank of each city in a state on the basis of count of glid in ascending order) and top_3_Calc which shows the top 3 values as "top values' and for all the rest of the cities it displays 'others'.However , i want all the others to be displayed as a single category "others" , and the top 3 cities to be displayed by their name displaying the sum total of count of all these cities. I hope i have made it clear

Comment: How about using a calculated field `City_formatted` instead of `City`? Definition would be something like `IF  [ranking] <= [Top 3] THEN [City] ELSE "Others" END`

Comment: It is still not merging all 'others' under a single category.If you want I can share the file with you.Please share your email id

Comment: I would have shared it via dropbox link so that everybody can see and help :)